# Why is this code unable to persist data?

Tags: ado.net, c#-2.0

```
public class Customer : BaseClass<Customer>
{   
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string TelephoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string InsuranceProvider { get; set; }
    public int? PolicyNumber { get; set; }
    public byte [] Photo { get; set; }
}
```

This message shows up:

[image]

Or, this:

[image]

How to modify this code to be able to persist data?

**CustomerDAO.cs**

```
class CustomerDAO
{
    .....
    public int Save(ITransactionManager tm, Customer item)
    {
        int count = -1;

        try
        {
            ISqlQueryExecutor<Customer> queryExecutor = new SqlQueryExecutor<Customer>(tm);

            count = 
                queryExecutor.
                ExecuteNonQuery(@"INSERT INTO Customer(
                                       ID
                                      ,Name
                                      ,TelephoneNumber
                                      ,DateOfBirth,
                                       InsuranceProvider,
                                       PolicyNumber)
                                  VALUES(
                                       @ID
                                      ,@Name
                                      ,@TelephoneNumber
                                      ,@DateOfBirth,
                                       @InsuranceProvider,
                                       @PolicyNumber)",
                                      item.ID,
                                      item.Name,
                                      item.TelephoneNumber,
                                      item.DateOfBirth,
                                      item.InsuranceProvider,
                                      item.PolicyNumber,item.Photo
                                      );
                                  //new DbParameter(item.ID, DbType.Int32),
                                  //new DbParameter(item.Name, DbType.String),
                                  //new DbParameter(item.TelephoneNumber, DbType.String),
                                  //new DbParameter(item.DateOfBirth, DbType.DateTime),
                                  //new DbParameter(item.InsuranceProvider, DbType.String),
                                  //new DbParameter(item.PolicyNumber, DbType.Int32)
                                  //new DbParameter(item.Photo, DbType.Binary)
                                  //);



            string str = string.Empty;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        return count;
    }
    .... ....
}
```

**CustomerBLL.cs**

```
class CustomerBLL
{
... ... ...
    public int Save(Customer item)
    {
        int newId = 0;

        ITransactionManager tm = ApplicationContext.Get(DBNameConst.ActiveConnStringName);

        try
        {
            tm.BeginTransaction();

            item.ID = newId = PivotTable.GetNextID(tm, "Customer").Value;

            customerDao.Save(tm, item);

            PivotTable.UpdateNextIdField(tm, "Customer", newId);

            tm.CommitTransaction();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            tm.RollbackTransaction();

            throw ex;
        }

        return newId;
    }
    ... ... ...
 }
```

**ASqlQueryExecutor.cs**

```
public abstract class ASqlQueryExecutor<T> : ISqlQueryExecutor<T>
{
 public virtual int ExecuteNonQuery(string queryString, params object[] parameters)
    {
        int count = -1;

        try
        {
            Command = ParameterAttacher.AttachSaveParameters(TransactionManager, queryString, parameters);
            Command.CommandText = queryString;
            count = Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        return count;
    }
```

**ParameterAttacher.cs**

```
class ParameterAttacher
{
    public static IDbCommand AttachSaveParameters(ITransactionManager tm, string queryString, params object [] argumentsList)
    {
        IDbCommand command = new DbObjectInstantiator(tm.ProviderName).CreateCommand();
        command.Connection = tm.Connection;
        command.Transaction = tm.Transaction;

        IList<string> parameterNamesList = new List<string>(ParameterParser.Parse(queryString));

        if (parameterNamesList.Count > 0 && argumentsList.Length == argumentsList.Length)
        {
            int i = 0;

            foreach (string paramName in parameterNamesList)
            {
                Attach(command, paramName, argumentsList[i]);

                ++i;
            }
        }

        return command;
    }

    public static void Attach(IDbCommand command, string paramName, object dbParam)
    {
        IDbDataParameter param = command.CreateParameter();

        param.ParameterName = paramName;
        param.Value = (dbParam==null) ? ((object)DBNull.Value) : dbParam;
        //param.DbType = dbParam.DbType;

        command.Parameters.Add(param);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try setting the DbType to VarBinary when making a parameter from a byte array.

Comment: Where? In the source-code or in SqlServer?

Comment: Both. You would have a varbinary column in the database and set the DbType on your parameter. There are also some other alternatives you could use to store images: You could have a varchar column in the database and encode your array into a base-64 string. You could store the image as a file and have the database just contain a pointer to the file.

Comment: Upvote for the great customer photo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> string or binary data would be truncated. the statement has been terminated

This could occur because you're trying to store too much data into a column.  For example, if you have an nvarchar(5) column in a database and you try to store "this is a string" in there, you might get that error because 5 characters can't hold all of "this is a string".

You can avoid this problem by limiting the fields in your UI to the same length as those in the database.  Or, you can perform a check in the validation methods.

> Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to binary is not allowed.

This seems fairly obvious: you're trying to store a character value in a binary column.  You haven't provided your database schema, so I can't tell for sure where this could be; but, if you have a column or sproc parameter in the database set as `binary` but your C# details it as `DbType.String` you might get this error.

#### UPDATE:

You never set your `DbType` in `ParameterAttacher.Attach`.  This means the `Parameter` will default to `DbType.AnsiString` for the parameter type.  If you pass it a `byte[]` it *may* convert that to an ansi string, but when the parameter is given to ADO, it will see *DbType.AnsiString* and compare that to `varbinary(50)` (or `money`, or `datetime`, or `int`, etc.) and throw an exception detailing that it doesn't know how to convert to `binary` (e.g. an implicit conversion).

Also, do yourself a favour and get rid of:

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
  throw ex;
}
```

That will just force you to loose the real location of the exception and cause you to waste time trying to figure out where the real problem is.

When you must catch (e.g. when you want to rollback the transaction, just `throw`, don't `throw ex`.  Just `throw` won't lose the stack information and you can track down the location of the exception.  For example:

```
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        tm.RollbackTransaction();

        throw;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but it is not addressing my problem. These two messages are occurring because of, I guess, when -(1) "byte [] Photo" has a value. I was actually using "binary" column to store image data. Later I changed it to varbinary. (2) "byte [] Photo" is null. According to my code, when "Photo"-property is null, DBNull.Value is tried to store in the sqlserver-"binary" field. But, DBNull.Value is not compatible with sql-"binary" field, as it is actually an nvarchar value. Whatever, my problem is still unsolved. I think I need to redesign my framework.

Comment: It may not be the DBNull.Value, it may be what you're telling ado what that value represents. If you tell ADO the value is a varchar but the column is binary then it will complain about null.  If you tell ADO that the null is binary, and the column is binary then null will be compatible. I don't know what your schema looks like, so I can't tell where you'd have a mismatch like this.

Comment: OK. Here is the schema. See the picture.